# Python - Trying to compare two text files that are formatted differently

Tags: python

File 1 is formatted like this:

```
1111111111
2222222222
```

File 2 is formatted like this:

```
3333333333:4444444444
1111111111:2222222222
```

I am trying to figure out a way to take the stuff in file one and see if it matches with *only* the stuff to the *right* of the colons in file two. The ultimate goal is to remove the FULL line in file two if there is a match.

I know I can cut file 2 using standard commands so they're formatted exactly the same. The problem is I need the finished file in 88888:99999 format and it seems too complicated to split them up only to put them back in the right order.

I've tried nesting for loops, regex, sets, lists, my head is spinning.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
   if line.split(":")[1] in keys:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Do you mean lines in file 2 should be deleted if *any* line in file 1 matches the component to the right of the colon, or matched up lines?

Comment: Yes. We can essentially ignore the stuff to the left of the colon completely but if a line in file 1 is anywhere in file 2, the whole line in file 2 should be removed...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to remove lines in file 2 if the second part of the line matches up with *any* value in file 1 you would do something like this:

```
# Warning: Untested code ahead
with open("file1", "r") as f1:
    # First, get the set of all the values in file 1
    # Sets use hash tables under the covers so this should
    # be fast enough for our use case (assuming sizes less than
    # the total memory available on the system)
    keys = set(f1.read().splitlines())

# Since we can't write back into the same file as we read through it
# we'll pipe the valid lines into a new file
with open("file2", "r") as f2:
    with open("filtered_file", "w") as dest:
        for line in f2:
            line = line.strip()  # Remove newline
            # ASSUMPTION: All lines in file 2 have a colon
            if line.split(":")[1] in keys:
                continue
            else:
                dest.writeline(line)
```

Comment: I think this is the correct algorithm. What does the [1] do in  if line.split(":")[1] ?

Comment: @Craig - `line.split(":")` splits the string into an array of strings (sans the ":" character and split on it).  `[1]` accesses the second entry in the array (in most programming languages arrays indexes start at zero).  So "1111111111:2222222222" `->` `["1111111111", "2222222222"]` and getting the second element in the array yields "2222222222" - which we then check against our list of disallowed values.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I assume the line should be if line.split(":",1) in keys:    if so, I am getting an unhashable list error. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Craig - no, it should be `line.split(":")[1]` - can you edit your question to show the code you are using and also include the stack trace you are getting?

Comment: Sean - I am using the exact code you posted, just with different file names. Stack trace posted above.....

Comment: @Craig - an `IndexError` is not a `TypeError` ;-) From what it looks like you have lines in file2 that do not have a colon in them - you'll want to `.count(":")` the number of colons first and then either keep or drop the lines that don't have colons in them (note the assumption called out in the code at that line).

Comment: The file definitely has colons in it. When I comment out the entire "if else" block and just do a "print line" - I see the first line printed but only one character on each line (which I believe is how readline() is supposed to work). I do see the colon show up too...

Comment: @Craig - whoops, I was iterating over only the *first* line in line 2 - updated my answer to iterate over *all* the lines :-)

Comment: Sean - getting closer! Still not getting any output or lines printed in the "else" statement but its reading all the lines now. I will keep digging. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd avoid reading the whole file and then splitting the lines using splitlines... you could just iterate over the file.

Comment: @Bakuriu - good point - and both ways are pretty much the same clarity-wise.  I've updated my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the elements right to colon in file 2. Maybe not the cleanest one, but you get the idea.

```
 str2 = open(file2).read()
 righttocolon = [s.split(":")[1] for s in [ln for ln in str2.split("\n")] if len(s.split(":")) == 2]
```